# how to get or create role in yii

Tags: yii, yii-components

I am a newbie to yii. I have stuck my mind with yii-tutorials for creating roles in yii. but I am not getting how can I create role in yii. means I want to create two roles `admin` & `staff` and I want to give different priviliage to them.
I have created a `role` in user table, but I am not getting that how can I create a role and can assign priviliages to them, please help me guys

Thanks in advance

Comment: This link might be of some help: [Getting to Understand Hierarchical RBAC Scheme](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/136/getting-to-understand-hierarchical-rbac-scheme/)

Comment: I am not getting one thing that where should I use this code

Comment: The logic is, in the Controller access rules, you check first if the user is logged in, and then what their role is, and assign different access rules for each role type

Answer (score 2):

In your copenents/UserIdentity.php

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity{
private $_id;



public function authenticate()
{
    $record=Members::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>trim($this->username)));

    if($record===null)
    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;

    else if($record->password!==md5(trim($this->password)))
    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;

    else
    {
        $this->_id=$record->id;
        $this->setState('username', $record->username);
        $this->setState('name', $record->name);
        $this->setState('type', $record->role);
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;

    }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}

public function getId()
{
    return $this->_id;
}

public function setId($id)
{
    $this->_id = $id;
}
}
```

You can create a new column name as "role". set the members type "admin" or "staff" to role column.

Be careful to that line.

```
$this->setState('type', $record->role);
```

Create a new helper file. /protected/helpers/RoleHelper.php

```
class RoleHelper {

public static function GetRole(){

    if (Yii::app()->user->type == "admin"){
        //set the actions which admin can access
        $actionlist = "'index','view','create','update','admin','delete'";
    }
    elseif (Yii::app()->user->type = "staff"){
        //set the actions which staff can access
        $actionlist = "'index','view','create','update'";
    }
    else {
        $actionlist = "'index','view'";
    }

    return $actionlist;

}

}
```

and in your controllers -> accessRules function

```
public function accessRules()
{

    return array(
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array(RoleHelper::GetRole()),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),

        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

and dont forget to add 'application.helpers.*' to /config/main.php

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.models.*',
    'application.components.*',
    'application.helpers.*',
),
```

Answer (score 2):

This source is pretty good specially for beginners..I am using this method till now:
[Simple RBAC in YII](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/328/simple-rbac/)

Just follow the instructions given while having your desired modifications.

Concrete Example:

**WebUser.php** (/components/WebUser.php)

```
<?php 
class WebUser extends CWebUser
{
    /**
     * Overrides a Yii method that is used for roles in controllers (accessRules).
     *
     * @param string $operation Name of the operation required (here, a role).
     * @param mixed $params (opt) Parameters for this operation, usually the object to access.
     * @return bool Permission granted?
     */
    public function checkAccess($operation, $params=array())
    {
        if (empty($this->id)) {
            // Not identified => no rights
            return false;
        }
        $role = $this->getState("evalRoles");

        if ($role === 'SuperAdmin') {
            return 'SuperAdmin'; // admin role has access to everything
        }
        if ($role === 'Administrator') {
            return 'Administrator'; // admin role has access to everything
        }
        if ($role === 'Professor') {
            return 'Professor'; //Regular Teaching Professor, has limited access
        }
        // allow access if the operation request is the current user's role
        return ($operation === $role);
    }
}
```

Just connect it with your **components/UserIdentity.php** and **config/main.php**:

```
'components' => array(
// ...
'user' => array(
    'class' => 'WebUser',
),
```

and thats it..

to check the role of the logged in:

```
Yii::app->checkAccess("roles");
where checkAccess is the name of your function in WebUser...
```

> Please note that evalRoles is a column in your table that will supply the role of an account (on my link provided, that would be the word **roles** used in the major part snippet)